# Intruder playing games with my home connection?

Tags: dns, router

Was checking my home router and this appears in my logs just as I try to log in.

[image: DNS query failed: Name: its_better_to_play_this_game_when_no_one_sees_you.ttcg.com, Type: 1, Error: no such name]

The log shows system issues, and after my login which is the listed IP, there's a message of a 'DNS' query with a clear troll saying

'DNS query failed: Name: its_better_to_play_this_game_when_no_one_sees_you.ttcg.com, Type: 1, Error: no such name'.

I'm pretty sure there's no legitamate DNS server with that name that's trying to be retrieved. I've had a strong suspicion something has been going on but I have barely the nuts and bolts understanding of Protocol security to know how this has happened.

Can someone please help shed light on this. I've no idea how this has happened and if someone can explain the further implication that someone can have access to my Server DNS query responses, i.e someone having full access to my home network, I will be ever grateful.

Comment: that's a DNS query, not a DNS server name

Answer (score 3):

That's probably nothing to worry about. To achieve these things it is enough that you visit a website where somebody has included an image from some non-existing or no longer existing domain, i.e. something like this in the [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) code of the page:

```
<img src="http://its_better_to_play_this_game_when_no_one_sees_you.ttcg.com/img.gif">
```

This way the browser will try to load this image from the given site and for this the browser needs to do a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) lookup of the given name, i.e. resolve it to an [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) so that a connection to this site can be established and the data received. Since no host with this name exists an DNS the lookup will fail and will result in the log entry you've seen in the router.

In short: nothing to worry about and that's why it's only shown as "notice" in the log file. And this does not indicate some kind of hack against your system.